# How can I test if a JS library is packaged correctly (in different environments)?

Tags: javascript, testing, packaging

I know normal software testing like unit test. This question is not about that.

Assume I am new to JS (and indeed) and am developing a JS library project, and intend to publish it to, e.g., npm. Because the ecosystem is complex, I will likely not be able to configure my project correctly for its **packaging**.
For example, I may have pointed `require` in `package.json` to an ES-Module file, while in fact it expects a CommonJS-Module file; however, I may have generated them correctly, but just misconfigured my `package.json`. This has nothing to do with my actual (functional) source code, but just the packaging configuration and packaging tools.

As there is not just `package.json`, but also lots of packaging and supporting tools (e.g. Vite, Rollup, etc), each involving their own configuration files, it is very likely I will make mistakes in their configurations, and resulting in the library unusable simply because of the packaging configuration.

How can I test that my packaging is correct, for different environments, without having to manually creating multiple test projects? Alternatively, how can I get suggestions on what *might* be the correct configuration or expected outcomes? What tools are available out there?

In particular, I'm thinking of something like a compatibility / coverage report. But other forms are also fine.